# Carry part of an element forward in a vector (without looping)

Tags: r

I have a vector with date and time. Some of the elements of the vector include the actual date (+time) and whatever time underneath it is its respective time. I want to fill row 2/3/4/5 with row 1's date Dec-17-15 while keeping the original time that was in those rows. Likewise I want the date in row 6 to extend to 7/8/9/10. Is there a way to do this without a loop? I would you appreciate any help

```
d["X1"]
                   X1
1   Dec-17-15 05:17PM
2             04:46PM
3             04:44PM
4             04:40PM
5             04:39PM
6   Dec-16-15 10:37PM
7             07:48PM
8             07:41PM
9             06:35PM
10            06:09PM
```

Comment: Hi @Jessica, can you show us the output of `dput(d)` so that people can try to help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are a couple of options.  The first uses packages, the second only base R.

**Option 1:** With `tidyr::separate()` and `zoo::na.locf()`.  To understand what's going on here, read the help files for each.  It basically splits the column on the space and then carries the previous values forward over the `NA`s.  Then we paste.

```
d$X1 <- with(
    tidyr::separate(d, X1, letters[1:2], " ", fill = "left"), 
    paste(zoo::na.locf(a), b)
)
```

**Option 2:** With only base R. This finds the dates, finds the elements that need the prefix, and pastes the necessary elements onto the times. The dates are found by looking for the space between the date and the time.

```
g <- grepl(" ", d$X1, fixed = TRUE)
d$X1[!g] <- paste(
    rep(sub(" .*", "", d$X1[g]), with(rle(g), lengths[!values])), 
    d$X1[!g]
)
```

No looping, as requested.  Both of these options give the following updated data frame `d`.

```
d
#                   X1
# 1  Dec-17-15 05:17PM
# 2  Dec-17-15 04:46PM
# 3  Dec-17-15 04:44PM
# 4  Dec-17-15 04:40PM
# 5  Dec-17-15 04:39PM
# 6  Dec-16-15 10:37PM
# 7  Dec-16-15 07:48PM
# 8  Dec-16-15 07:41PM
# 9  Dec-16-15 06:35PM
# 10 Dec-16-15 06:09PM
```

**Note:**  Option 2 assumes `X1` is a character column.  If `X1` is a factor, you will need to precede Option 2 with `d$X1 <- as.character(d$X1)`.  We don't need to be concerned with that in Option 1 because `tidyr::separate()` does that conversion for us.

**Data:**

```
d <- structure(list(X1 = c("Dec-17-15 05:17PM", "04:46PM", "04:44PM", 
"04:40PM", "04:39PM", "Dec-16-15 10:37PM", "07:48PM", "07:41PM", 
"06:35PM", "06:09PM")), .Names = "X1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```